# Отобразить в ListView json-файл из папки assets

Tags: java, android, json

У меня есть json файл который я сохранил в папке assets . Не могу понять почему он не выводит на экран мой json. Я его передаю в ListView

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> flyreport;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        flyreport = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.flyreport);


    }

    public String readJson(){
        String json = null;
        try{
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("flightsreport.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(readJson());
            JSONArray m_jArry = obj.getJSONArray("flights");
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> flyList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> m_li;

            for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);

               String flightid_value = jo_inside.getString("flightid");
               String uid_value = jo_inside.getString("uid");
               String status_value = jo_inside.getString("status");
               String opsstatus_value = jo_inside.getString("opsstatus");
               String call_sign_number_value = jo_inside.getString("call_sign_number");
               String call_sign_code_value = jo_inside.getString("call_sign_code");
               String std_value = jo_inside.getString("std");
               String sta_value = jo_inside.getString("sta");

                //Add your values in your `ArrayList` as below:
                m_li = new HashMap<String, String>();
                m_li.put("flightid", flightid_value);
                m_li.put("uid", uid_value);
                m_li.put("sta", sta_value);
                m_li.put("status", status_value);
                m_li.put("opsstatus",opsstatus_value);
                m_li.put("call_sign_number", call_sign_number_value);
                m_li.put("call_sign_code", call_sign_code_value);
                m_li.put("std_value", std_value);
                flyList.add(m_li);
                //adapter to set response in textview
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        MainActivity.this,flyreport,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"flightid_value","uid_value","status_value","opsstatus_value",
                "call_sign_number_value", "call_sign_code_value", "std_value", "sta_value"}, new int [] {R.id.flightid, R.id.uid,
                R.id.opsstatus,R.id.status,R.id.call_sign_code,R.id.call_sign_number,R.id.sta,R.id.std});
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
            }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return json;
        }
}
```

Это разметка ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/flightid"
        android:text="flightid: "
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="#43bd00"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/uid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:textColor="#acacac" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="status: "
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opsstatus"
        android:text="opsstatus: "
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="#43bd00"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/call_sign_number"
        android:text="call_sign_number: "
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:textColor="#acacac" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/call_sign_code"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="call_sign_code: "
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/std"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="std: "
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="sta: "
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Метод `readJson()` надо вызвать - он сам выполниться не догадается, инициализацию адаптера вынести за пределы цикла и отдать ему `flyList` вместо пустого `flyreport`

Comment: я добавил метод readJson в OnCreate .

Comment: я его вынес за цикл все равно не выводит текст !!!!

Comment: передал адаптреу flyList

Comment: Eщё один косяк: `new JSONObject(readJson())` => `new JSONObject(new String(buffer))`

Comment: это тоже исправил , все равно нечего((((

Comment: Мап заполняете с одними ключами, а адаптеру даёте другие `"flightid"` - `"flightid_value"`. Но если список совсем пустой, то смотрите в LogCat какие ошибки выдаются.